# How to print feedback and points using Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I created a function to return the outcomes using Microsoft Graph Education API. I want to print feedback and points but I can’t, they don’t exist. Here is the code:

```cs
public static async Task<IEnumerable<EducationOutcome>> GetOutcomesForSubmission()
{
  var outcomes = await graphClient
    .Education
    .Classes["8557483b-a233-4710-82de-e1bdb03bb9a9"]
    .Assignments["1b09cd43-cf87-4cef-a043-ae3d6160c200"]
    .Submissions["d4486e20-1b47-4b5b-720c-0fe0038d4882"]
    .Outcomes
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

  return outcomes;
}

public static void ListOutcomes()
{
  var outcomes = GetOutcomesForSubmission().Result;

  Console.WriteLine("Outcomes:\n");

  foreach (var v in outcomes)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"User id: {v.LastModifiedBy.User.Id}, Submission id: {v.Id}");
  }

  Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `GetAsync()` isn't returning a collection of `EducationOutcome` objects. It is returning an `EducationSubmissionOutcomesCollectionPage` instead. To get the actual results, you need to return the `CurrentPage` property.

```cs
public static async Task<IEnumerable<EducationOutcome>> GetOutcomesForSubmission()
{
  var response = await graphClient
    .Education
    .Classes["8557483b-a233-4710-82de-e1bdb03bb9a9"]
    .Assignments["1b09cd43-cf87-4cef-a043-ae3d6160c200"]
    .Submissions["d4486e20-1b47-4b5b-720c-0fe0038d4882"]
    .Outcomes
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

  return response.CurrentPage.ToList();
}
```

Note that this will only return the first page of data. If you want to grab all of the data, you'll need to page through using the `response.NextPageRequest` property:

```cs
var outcomes = response.CurrentPage.ToList();
while (response.NextPageRequest != null)
{
    response = await response.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    outcomes.AddRange(response.CurrentPage);

}
return outcomes;
```

Keep in mind that `EducationOutcome` is a *base class*, so it will only contain properties common across all "Outcome" types (which in this case is pretty little). If you want a specific type of Outcome, you'll need to cast it to the specific type first:

```cs
foreach (var v in outcomes)
{
  if (v is EducationRubricOutcome)
  {
    var outcome = v as EducationRubricOutcome;
    Console.WriteLine($"User id: {outcome.LastModifiedBy.User.Id}, Submission id: {outcome.Id}, Feedback Count: {outcome.RubricQualityFeedback.Count}");
  }
  else if (v is EducationPointsOutcome)
  {
    var outcome = v as EducationPointsOutcome;
    Console.WriteLine($"User id: {outcome.LastModifiedBy.User.Id}, Submission id: {outcome.Id}, Points: {outcome.Points.Points}");
  }
  else if (v is EducationFeedbackOutcome)
  {
    var outcome = v as EducationFeedbackOutcome;
    Console.WriteLine($"User id: {outcome.LastModifiedBy.User.Id}, Submission id: {outcome.Id}, Feedback: {outcome.Feedback.Text}");
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it still won't show feedback and points. I can only print certain properties such as: Id, LastModifiedBy and LastModifiedDateTime.

Comment: That is because you're returning the base class (`EducationOutcome`) rather than `EducationPointsOutcome`. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: I tried it and it works. Thank you very much!